# openlayers3 : get strategy type from ol.source.vector object?

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a way to get the type of strategy used in an openlayers3 `ol.source.vector` object ?

With ol-debug.js I can loop over source objet att and get the `strategy_` key but with ol.js has the key a fixed name?

I need to refresh a layer building a new source object that would have the same strategy than the initial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no way to access the strategy through the API, but we welcome a pull request (PR) adding getStrategy(). See this PR for inspiration: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/commit/908d4051cdef02c472565ccd25482a88e3c50f84#diff-588fbc85cf5a11dfa082ea47608d6729

Comment: i just opened an issue on github #6368 to discuss the opportunity to add a getter on the loading strategy or on the options set at the ol.source creation.